# Simple Injector - Delayed Initialization

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Could someone assist me with one question please?

I have two services.

***GAuth:***

```
public class GAuth : IGAuth
{
    public async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecrets clientSecrets)
    {
        using (var cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            var localServerCodeReceiver = new LocalServerCodeReceiver();

            cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));

            return await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                clientSecrets,
                _scopes,
                User,
                cts.Token,
                new FileDataStore(string.Empty), localServerCodeReceiver
            );
        }
    }
}
```

***GDrive:***

```
public class GDrive : IGDrive
{
    private readonly DriveService _driveService;

    public GDrive(UserCredential userCredential)
    {
        _driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = userCredential,
            ApplicationName = string.Empty
        });
    }
}
```

***And registration part:***

```
container.Register<IGAuth, GAuth>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Register<IGDrive, GDrive>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

As you can see `GAuth` service returns `UserCredentials` object after authorization. And this `UserCredentials` is required for `GDrive` service.
It's simplified example, but in general I need to initialize `GDrive` service with correct `UserCredentials` object after user press `Auth` button on the application form.

Is there any way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Instead of passing the `UserCredential` to the constructor of `GDrive`, can you create an `Initialize` method which tak the `UserCredential` into parameter? This way you can artificially delay the execution.

Comment: @fharreau, yes, I can, and looks like it will work, but I trying to understand what is the best approach for resolving this problem given the fact that I working using DI approach. So maybe we can use `Context based injection` or something else... I don't know. Anyway, thanks for proposed solution.

Comment: I have no idea, I don't know SimpleInjector :D. At first sight, I would say there is a problem with your design: You are registering your `GDrive` as a singleton and want to configure it inside its constructor. This means that every user will use the same configuration (the configuration of the first user). If you have only one user or if this is exactly the behavior you want, then forget what I just said :D.

Comment: The application you are working on is an ASP.NET application? Then there must exist a `PerSession` lifestyle or something like that, that would be "at first sight" :3 more appropriate. Then the approach I suggest you looks very reasonable in terms of complexity/maintainability/readability.

Comment: @fharreau, no - it's WPF application. Also your second assumption is right - I have only one active user during application session.

Comment: Then one solution would be to register at the end of `AuthorizeAsync` the `UserCredential` into your container. Most of the IoC container do not instantiate their instances until they are actually requested. So if you can ensure that your container will never be requested for `GDrive` before the call to `AuthorizeAsync`, that should work... But I would never recommand this. While it should work now, it is possible that in the future, the `GDrive` will be requested before and your whole architecture will be questionned.

Comment: Another solution would be to provide to `GAuth` the `GDrive` singleton and initialize it during the call to `AuthorizeAsync`. This way, the initialization is done only once and you do not need to check for its initialization at each use of `GDrive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a design perspective, injection constructors should be [simple, fast and reliable](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/03/03/InjectionConstructorsshouldbesimple/). This isn't the case in your case, since the building of the object graph depends on I/O.

Instead, you should postpone the IO till after the constructor has ran.

There are two things that come to my mind that you can do. Either you inject the `IGAuth` into the GDrive and make sure it is called after the constructor has ran, or you inject a lazy async `UserCredential` that can be requested after the constructor has ran.

Here's an example of the latter:

```
public class GDrive : IGDrive
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<DriveService>> _driveService;

    public GDrive(Lazy<Task<UserCredential>> userCredential)
    {
        _driveService = new Lazy<Task<DriveService>>(async () =>
            new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = await userCredential.Value,
                ApplicationName = string.Empty
            }));
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        var service = await _driveService.Value;

        service.DoSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

You can configure this `GDrive` as follows:

```
var auth = new GAuth();
var credentials = new Lazy<Task<UserCredential>>(
    () => auth.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets()));

container.RegisterSingleton<IGDrive>(new GDrive(credentials));
```

The other option is to inject the `GAuth` into the `GDrive`. That would result in something as follows:

```
public class GDrive : IGDrive
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task<DriveService>> _driveService;

    public GDrive(IGAuth auth)
    {
        _driveService = new Lazy<Task<DriveService>>(async () =>
            new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = await auth.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets()),
                ApplicationName = string.Empty
            }));
    }

    public async Task SomeMethod()
    {
        var service = await _driveService.Value;

        service.DoSomeStuff();
    }
}
```

Note that in both cases a `Lazy<Async<T>>` is created that will ensure that the asynchronous operation is only triggered when `Lazy<T>.Value` is called for the first time.

Comment: thanks for explanation. This example with `Lazy<>` approach works fine for me, BUT... It works only for first user login, but in my application we have possibility to change the user, and if we press `ChangeUser` button then `UserCredential` object will be changed and `GData` service becomes invalid and stops working.

Comment: In that case, you're better of with an `IUserContext` abstraction that exposes an `Task<UserCredential> UserCredential` property. You can inject this `IUserContext` into `GDrive` and have an implementation of `IUserContext` that allows the user to be changed while the application is running. Or, in case possible, present the user with prompt for login on application startup, and require the user to restart the application when he wishes to switch users. This allows you to make the `UserCredentials` static and it allows it to be created before you register your components.